# "não é um jdk java home valido"

Tags: java, oracle

Estou tentando instalar o weblogic 12c a partir de um .jar.

Executo o comando `java -jar wls_121200.jar` , porém o CMD me retorna

> Este instalador deve ser executado usando o Java Development Kit (JDK),
>       porém, C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131 não é um JDK Java Home válido.
>       Falha do Oracle Universal Installer.

Já tenho o jdk instalado e o **JAVA_HOME** apontando para o JDK, porém não encontrei nenhuma solução para esse problema.

Comment: Fez isso recente? Perguntas bobas mas, reiniciou o PC ? Mostra o print da sua instalação do jdk do seu JAVA_HOME setado. Já tentou setar o JAVA_HOME dentro do seu script ? O que está me parecendo que tem um JAVA_HOME apontando pra este diretório.

Comment: @Douglas Encontrei a resposta. Já tinha feito esses passos ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lendo a [documentação da oracle para o weblogic](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/WLSIG/install_gui.htm#WLSIG197), o .jar deve ser instalado a partir da pasta `\bin` do JDK.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin\java -jar wls_121200.jar
```

Comment: De toda forma, seu JAVA_HOME "válido" está apontando pra um lugar correto, se sua variável PATH está certa devia funcionar só com `java -jar`.

Comment: @Douglas Pois é douglas, todas as variáveis ambientes estão apontando para o lugar correto.

Answer (score 2):

Tive o mesmo problema, eu tenho o jdk e o jre instalados no windows e a variável de ambiente está apontada para o jdk mas mesmo assim o windows aponta para o jre. Então a solução foi colar o instalador (.jar) dentro da pasta bin **(EX: **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin**)** onde esta instalado o jdk, depois rode novamente o **java -jar nomeDoArquivo.jar** e pronto vai funcionar !

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando instalar o servidor WebLogic, porém um pré-requisito é ter o JDK instalado na máquina.

A mensagem de erro está acusando justamente isso, que você tem instalado o **JRE** e não o **JDK**.

baixe e instale o JDK por esse link: [JDK Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Após isso, tente novamente a instalação do seu programa.

Answer (score 0):

Basta declarar o caminho para o jdk na variavel PATH de forma que venha antes de outras instalações java, por exemplo JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241 e PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin:$PATH

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Eu consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

**Propriedades do Sistema** -> **Variáveis de Ambiente**

Na zona "**Variáveis do sistema**" veja se encontra algum **valor** referenciando algum caminho **java**, no meu caso encontrei na variável **Path** que estava relacionado ao Oracle.

No meu caso, como essa referência era somente para um atalho do jre, eu só fiz deletar e já voltou a funcionar.
É importante lembrar de reiniciar o prompt.

Answer (score -4):

Eu consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

**Propriedades do Sistema** -> **Variáveis de Ambiente**

Na zona "**Variáveis do sistema**" veja se encontra algum **valor** referenciando algum caminho **java**, no meu caso encontrei na variável **Path** que estava relacionado ao Oracle.

No meu caso, como essa referência era somente para um atalho do jre, eu só fiz deletar e já voltou a funcionar.
É importante lembrar de reiniciar o prompt.